# How do I edit a certain char in the following?

Tags: c, pointers, char, calloc

So I have the following code:

```
char *something = (char *) calloc(LENGTH, sizeof(char));
```

The length is defined as 10.
I'm imaging it like this in memory:

### |  [0]  |  [1]  |  [2]  |  [3]  |  [4]  |  [5]  |  [6]  |  [7]  |  [8]  |  [9]  |  \0  |

How would I change [1] without defining the whole char? And then be able to define [2], and so on...

Each change must not affect the previous change!

Thank you!

Comment: That '\0' you show there seems to be in cell `[10]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't that the sentinel to let the compiler know it's reached the end?

Comment: You have to allocate space for the sentinel yourself. And remember to delete the whole thing.

Comment: @TapThat: no such sentinel exists, that sentinel is used in string literals and as convenience for all methods that work on `const char*` interpreted as strings. You are just allocating raw memory.

Comment: @TapThat Yes, properly-formed strings have that sentinel.  But you have not created a string here.  You've allocated 10 bytes, so the 11th cell isn't there.

Comment: As a matter of fact, since you called `calloc`, the 10 bytes you did allocate will all start out containing `\0`.  (But not the 11th.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The length is defined as 10. I'm imaging it like this in memory

Incorrect. First, there are only 10 bytes (your picture shows 11) and second, all of them are filled with `'\0'` (which `calloc()` does).

> How would I change [1] without defining the whole char? And then be able to define [2], and so on...

By "change" if you mean assigning values then you can index them like:

```
something[1] = 'a';
something[5] = 'q';
```

and so on.

But do remember, using it as a C-string may not work (for example, printing `something` using `printf("%s", something);`) since there are intermediate zero bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
char *something = (char *) calloc(LENGTH, sizeof(char));
```

gives you 10 (not 11) bytes, all initialised to 0.

You can change any byte in here you want

```
something[1] ='?';
```

If you use standard routine to e.g. `printf` this it will of course then find '0' in the first byte and interpret it as the end of a string.

Don't forget to free it when you are done

```
free(something);
```